# celery task routing with CELERY_ROUTES not working with task subclasses

Tags: python, django, celery

I am using celery 3.0.20 and I have difficulties getting celery tasks to work with different queues.

My celery workers are launched with the queue configuration

```
-Q:w1 default -Q:w2 longrunning
```

The Django settings contains the following celery config:

```
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
    Queue('longrunning', Exchange('longrunning'), routing_key='longrunning'),
)
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'direct'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'default'

CELERY_ROUTES = ({'mytasks.task_a.run': {
                    'queue': 'longrunning',
                    'routing_key': 'longrunning'
             }},
```

So far, so good. All tasks go by default in the `default` queue, and `task_a` goes into the long-running queue.

The `task_a` module is implemented as follows:

```
from celery import task

@task
def run():
    # do some task work
```

Now, I have the problem that a different task is implemented as a class inheriting from `celery.Task`:

```
from celery import Task

class AnotherTask(Task):

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some task work
```

When the `AnotherTask` class now resides in `task_b` module, I cannot make this task to be executed in the `longrunning` queue: I tried adding it to `CELERY_ROUTES` in different varieties, none of them worked:

```
{'mytasks.task_b': {
    'queue': 'longrunning',
     'routing_key': 'longrunning'
}}
```

-

```
{'mytasks.task_b.AnotherTask': {
    'queue': 'longrunning',
     'routing_key': 'longrunning'
}}
```

-

```
{'mytasks.task_b.AnotherTask.run': {
    'queue': 'longrunning',
     'routing_key': 'longrunning'
}}
```

I also tried to switch to default exchange type `'topic'`, but that didn't work either.

Any hints how to get the task in class `AnotherTask` to be executed in the `longrunning` queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the problem.

It was due to the fact that all other tasks, ending up in the `longrunning` queue, where started regularly with *celerybeat*. The new task was started from the web environment. And the celerybeat settings imported the settings containing the `CELERY_ROUTES` dict, the web environment settings did not. Ugh!